# Is it possible to allow a cmd command line script in the firewall of windows?

Tags: windows, firewall

I have a cmd file with this command line:

```
curl.exe --output index.html --url https://aaaa.com
```

But I get an error that says it is not possible to communicate with the url in the port xxx.

If I create a rule for the tcp port XXX the it works, but I would like to know if it is possible to create a rule for an application, in this case is a cmd script, but I the wizard to create the rule it only allows .exe applications, no batch files.

So I would like to know if it is possible to create a rule for a cmd instead to open the port.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a firewall rule that will pertains to all the commands
that are included in a batch script or a CMD session.

You need to create a rule for each program that makes internet calls
that is found  inside the batch script or a CMD session.

In this case, this means creating a rule for `curl.exe`.